# Calculate dynamic column values based on start date and end date

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to calculate the per year depreciation value of items based on start date and end date and value of the item. Below screenshots clearly explain further.

[image: Desired result value tabs]

[image: Calculation criteria tabs]

Comment: How did you arrive at 11,311?

Comment: @JNevill It's average divided by 10 rounded to nearest intiger :) Now the question is why?

Comment: Avergage what? Like Average of the absolute value of the year-over-year value?

Answer (score 1):

I honestly thought the formula would be more complex; e.g. taking the portion of 90484 that is proportionate to 5/15/2018 but your desired results are returned by a simple averageifs/10.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B2:I2, B1:I1, ">="&YEAR(C5), B1:I1, "<="&YEAR(D5))/10
```

[image]

Comment: You get +1 only cause you added image :)

Comment: Well, seeing as how my result was $ 0.50 off, I wanted to justify the result.

Comment: I was just joking, your answer is fine, it is the question that should be closed as unclear.